# Versioning my copy of WordPress

Tags: wordpress, backup

Get WordPress and a host ready. Install it, add plugins. Customize at your will. That will give us many files and a database.

We are already keeping every file on any given Version Control System (actually GIT SVN).

So, what's the best way to keep that "backup" fully and easily recoverable?

<sub>I believe that "best way" would be a simple and/or automated way (unlike [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893513/how-to-copy-transfer-wordpress-sites-from-one-location-to-another/4893761#4893761)) to backup and recover the database with just one click.</sub>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To backup, use tar & mysqldump commands. These are Open standards, so accepted everywhere & having no bug.
**Backup files with tar command:**

```
$ tar -cvzf /path/to/storage/backup.tar /path/to/wordpress/installation
```

To restore files, simply untar it. **An example:**

```
$ tar -C /path/to/wordpress/installation -xvzf /path/to/storage/backup.tar
```

**Backup database with MySQLdump command:**

```
$ mysqldump --opt -u [uname] -p[password] [dbname] > [backupfile.sql]
```

To restore database, simply execute sql dump file by mysql command. **An example:**

```
$ mysql -u [uname] -p[password] [db_to_restore] < [backupfile.sql]
```

Make sure there's no space between -p & password.
It will work no matter how large your database is (phpMyAdmin can't be used to backup & restore large databases). MySQLdump is somewhat slower than other raw methods, but its bug-free & effective.

To do automation, use these commands as cron jobs' command.

Answer (score 0):

Try Wordpress plugin [XCloner Backup and Restore](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/xcloner-backup-and-restore/). It might help you beyond SVN. Setup a cron job for automation...

Comment: I have actually [already tried it](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/versioning-my-copy-of-wordpress?replies=1) and it ain't that easy to setup as I initially thought. I could get to backup only the database but restoring it is harsh.

Comment: Check out my another answer. As per your requirement just change the parameters.